# css: How display right of some li tags

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm creating a content slider with ul and li like:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li id="left">content</li>
<li id="left">content</li>
<li id="left">content</li>
<li id="right">content</li>
<li id="right">content</li>
<li id="right">content</li>
</ul>
<ul id="content_show">
<li>content show</li>
....ect
</ul>
</div>
```

Now I want to show 3 contents on the left and 3 on the right and slider between of both.
I make to show all li id=(left and right) on the left and slider on the right but I cannot set li id="right" on the right listed.

How can display id="right" on the right of slider?

Like:

```
text               text
text CONTENTSLIDER text
text               text
```

Comment: What css do you already have? Also you should use ids only once per page, for `left` and `right` you should use css classes.

Comment: Please create a [jsFiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code.

Comment: You can only use an ID once in HTML. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use style's or css file, and give the div `tabs` width, abd each li use `float` style
try to use `class="left" and class="right"`

```
#tabs { width:600px;} //example
.left { float:left;}
.right { float:right;}
```

Comment: I use style. I set float:left for left id and float:right for right id, this is not the same?

Comment: this is similar, try to use classes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get what you really want but maybe you can use the `float:right` attribute for all the li you want to go to the right!